# Redirecting to a Facelet is not working when extending FaceletViewHandler

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I'm overriding the handleRenderResponse method defined in com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler:

```
protected void handleRenderException(FacesContext context, Exception ex)
```

I'm overriding this method so I can redirect the user to a custom error page (which contain the desired look and feel and other stuff). This is the way I'm trying to

```
String errorPage = "/error.xhtml";          
String contextPath = context.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();          
String errorPagePath = contextPath+errorPage;
context.getExternalContext().redirect(errorPagePath);
```

The previous code is what I'm using to perform the redirect to this custom error page. Anyway, when I perform the redirect I'm prompted with a download dialog (this is with Internet Explorer, in Firefox the page does not display properly or as I would expect). I tried changing "/error.xhtml" to "/error.jsf"  but in that case I get a 404 error.

Somehow I think that the XHTML file is not being handled to the Facelets ViewHandler after the redirect, if I open the downloaded xhtml file I can see that the EL expressions were not resolved and the the ui tags were not handled. I don't have problems with other pages in my application, only when doing the redirect programatically.

Important data from my web.xml:

**facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS is set to *.xhtml**

**javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX is set to .xhtml**

**servlet-mapping for the "Faces Servlet" is "*.jsf" and "/faces/*"**

Comment: Any reason that you don't use `<error-page>` in `web.xml`?

Comment: I may do that, but actually I want to be able to dynamically have more control about what is going to happen when an exception occurs (like calling specific navigation rules or updating managed beans, updating session data, etc.). I'm not sure if I could have that amount of control if I use error-page, what do you think?

Comment: It can be a JSF(XHTML) page. You can attach a managed bean to it. A managed bean has access to the `FacesContext`. Do the math :) By the way, when commenting on other's comments in non-others' posts, use `@name` to get them notified immediately about that. I didn't see your comment until I peeked along. Also see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have/35913#35913)

Comment: @BalusC, sorry for neglecting this post for so long, but once I solved my problem I forgot to update. I ended using a mixed approach, I'm using both the error-page element, and I'm also providing a customized view handler where I'm overriding handleRenderException so that for very specific error conditions I can take special actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with one of the Facelets templates, this template contained an error that once solved allowed the application to work properly.